# How to allow any generic to be passed as argument?

Tags: javascript, class, flowtype

How can I declare an type which will allow a type of any generic to be allowed to be passed?  Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
/* @flow */

type InterfaceType = {
    var1 : number,
};

type ActualType = InterfaceType & {
    var2 : string,
};

class StateOne<T : InterfaceType> {
    constructor(arg : T) : StateOne<T> {
        return this;
    }
}

class StateTwo {
    constructor(stateOne : StateOne<InterfaceType>) : StateTwo {
        return this;
    }
}

let variable : ActualType = {
    var1: 1,
    var2: "text",
}

let stateOne : StateOne<ActualType> = new StateOne(variable);
let stateTwo : StateTwo = new StateTwo(stateOne);
```

Here is the flow error I'm getting:

```
    29: let stateTwo : StateTwo = new StateTwo(stateOne);
                                               ^ Cannot call `StateTwo` with `stateOne` bound to `stateOne` because property `var2` is missing in `InterfaceType` [1] but exists in object type [2] in type argument `T` [3].
        References:
        18:     constructor(stateOne : StateOne<InterfaceType>) : StateTwo {
                                              ^ [1]
        7: type ActualType = InterfaceType & {
                                             ^ [2]
        11: class StateOne<T : InterfaceType> {
                           ^ [3]
```

My thought was that since `ActualType` is a more specific `InterfaceType`, then I would be able to pass `StateOne<ActualType>` as an argument that requires `StateOne<InterfaceType>`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the error by adding a generic to the constructor:

```
class StateTwo {
    constructor<T : InterfaceType>(stateOne : StateOne<T>) : StateTwo {
        return this;
    }
}
```